# Why does uploading same file caused an error?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing a tool which need to compare 2 files. But, I got an error everytime I select or upload same file. Here is my code:

```
Dim File1 As String, File2 As String
Dim wbCopyF1 As Workbook, wbCopyF2 As Workbook, wbCopyT As Workbook
Dim wsCopyF1 As Worksheet, wsCopyF2 As Worksheet
Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long

Set wbCopyT = Workbooks.Add

File1 = txtBoxOld.Text
File2 = txtBoxNew.Text

'Open the path location of selected file
Set wbCopyF1 = Workbooks.Open(File1)
Set wsCopyF1 = wbCopyF1.Sheets(1)
Set wbCopyF2 = Workbooks.Open(File2)
Set wsCopyF2 = wbCopyF2.Sheets(1)

'Filter the application and copy Range from Previous file
LR1 = wsCopyF1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
wsCopyF1.Range("A2:D2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Me.txtBoxApplication, VisibleDropDown:=True
wsCopyF1.Range("A2:D" & LR1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wbCopyT.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
wbCopyF1.Close SaveChanges:=False

'Filter the application and copy Range from Latest file
LR2 = wsCopyF2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
wsCopyF2.Range("A2:D2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Me.txtBoxApplication, VisibleDropDown:=True
wsCopyF2.Range("A2:D" & LR2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wbCopyT.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
wbCopyF2.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I got an error like this:

[image]

And, the error pointed in this code: `LR1 = wsCopyF1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row`

The expected is that, whether I only have 1 file I can use the same file without experiencing any errors. Is there something wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @fbueckert - I edited my post. THank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a file two times within Excel (you can even not open 2 different files that have the same name but live in different folder). If you try, Excel will close and reopen that file

You can check this by modifying the file (e.g. write something in a cell) - Excel will ask you if you want to reopen the file and lose the modifications. However, if the file was not modified, Excel will reopen the file without further notification.

Reopening the file will invalidate the reference of the first workbook variable (`wbCopyF1`) and also of the first worksheet variable (`wsCopyF1`). And if you access one of these variables, you will get the automation error.